# MarkLogic - XDMP:node-replace not showing results as expected

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to create an endpoint that will be used for ingest of content.

When I receive a JSON Document, I am trying to submit it to a Semantic Classification Service, get the tags, and add it to the document.

Right now I can receive the document, send it to classification, get the tags just fine. Printing the logs shows that  `$tags` is populated with

```
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Greenville", "score":"1.00", "cskey":"43236", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"43236", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"5b1c5c25-f532-4fa9-a5c6-65eab0972032"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Philadelphia", "score":"0.83", "cskey":"415938", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"415938", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"6cadfcd3-6a91-476d-a313-ed6f6fab7b3b"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Russia", "score":"0.99", "cskey":"226313", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"226313", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"7fc9223e-e922-422d-b3fc-ed97b531eed6"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"South Carolina", "score":"0.69", "cskey":"299308", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"299308", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"82610e94-2f6e-4f4b-adde-c05dd9f4491c"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Spartanburg", "score":"1.00", "cskey":"300651", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"300651", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"b32a9141-83be-49b9-91e2-afdcece7e180"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Pennsylvania", "score":"0.84", "cskey":"248736", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"248736", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"b6697012-bb0d-4b52-8a16-157fed1f1658"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"White House", "score":"0.48", "cskey":"243472", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"243472", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"d69f639d-01a7-4273-9a92-835f6ce6bf18"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Charleston", "score":"1.00", "cskey":"48402", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"48402", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"da4c7ff4-edb2-412b-84e7-00b87531ef10"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Detroit", "score":"0.58", "cskey":"247983", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"247983", "original_key":"0", "name":"Location", "id":"e957c0f1-4307-47b4-9e64-4bf9df40ce23"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Chaka Fattah", "score":"0.51", "cskey":"2447795", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"2447795", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"09d4c57e-8581-4851-b059-fa6a2c139fa3"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Hillary Clinton", "score":"0.61", "cskey":"4186582", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"4186582", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"3a2c01e0-e0c8-4619-ac91-6c214084d92b"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Martin Luther King Jr.", "score":"0.48", "cskey":"2973808", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"2973808", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"632e2dd0-3599-44eb-b03c-824098102da9"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Mitt Romney", "score":"0.49", "cskey":"2089044", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"2089044", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"714d7f31-0d84-42c0-9ab8-691bc37efece"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Thomas Davis", "score":"0.49", "cskey":"1948480", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"1948480", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"ae4022ce-735a-4b05-a5e4-d8b400fd69a4"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Jonathan Allen", "score":"0.48", "cskey":"2511948", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"2511948", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"aefda552-f582-4951-a053-824f4ff8fe78"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Jonathan Capehart", "score":"0.48", "cskey":"4741366", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"4741366", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"be35ab01-fd3f-49a8-a119-a9f7c1a1d692"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Howard Dean", "score":"0.49", "cskey":"3887714", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"3887714", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"c8672836-ef35-452c-a049-10079cb790bf"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Thomas Davis", "score":"0.49", "cskey":"1731508", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"1731508", "original_key":"0", "name":"Person", "id":"cb53685e-8261-4ad4-a3ab-6da348b026f3"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Gun politics", "score":"0.42", "cskey":"5509249", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"5509249", "original_key":"0", "name":"Subject", "id":"03df7c0d-d07d-47d7-9b75-ac9c2df5970e"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Gun control", "score":"0.44", "cskey":"5242478", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"5242478", "original_key":"0", "name":"Subject", "id":"5534bc22-b2e5-44cd-a37e-4280e2fea604"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Gun violence", "score":"0.48", "cskey":"5529178", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"5529178", "original_key":"0", "name":"Subject", "id":"60214456-6ebc-4ea5-92eb-89274bf02d6b"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Climate", "score":"0.41", "cskey":"5345616", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"5345616", "original_key":"0", "name":"Subject", "id":"65e8b0ac-f853-43d5-a92c-842947f3fdd3"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Shootings", "score":"0.52", "cskey":"5470240", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"5470240", "original_key":"0", "name":"Subject", "id":"b593e4f0-cf7a-4234-8ce9-3beba31a16bb"}
2017-10-20 15:29:40.333 Info: App-Services: {"value":"Violence", "score":"0.42", "cskey":"5428634", "tag_source":"smartlogic", "key":"5428634", "original_key":"0", "name":"Subject", "id":"f8eaed62-64b1-4125-8878-4088f1aef13d"}
```

The document I am trying to update is JSON. I am trying to replace the node of `tags` which will either be **Null** or **Empty Array-node []**

Per the docks of `xdmp:node-replace` I am trying to do the following line

`let $_ := xdmp:node-replace($doc//headers/tags, array-node { $tags  }  )`

This does not seem to apply the expect results (update document with tags)
I issue a `xdmp:document-insert` at the end of the code to make sure we insert the updated version.

### Current Query Console

```
let $doc_uri := '/adocument.json'
let $doc := fn:doc($doc_uri)

(: content used for submission :)
let $content := $doc//description
let $title := $doc//title
let $smart_uri := 'http://10.203.10.229:5058'
let $body := fn:concat($title,'&#10;',$content )
let $xml_payload := 
    <request op="CLASSIFY">
        <document>
            <body type="TEXT"> {$body}</body>
            <path/>
            <multiarticle/>
            <language>Default</language>
            <threshold>1</threshold>
            <clustering type="RMS" threshold="1"/>
            <operation_mode>CAT</operation_mode>
            <feedback/>
            <use_generated_keys/>
        </document>
    </request>

let $test := xdmp:quote($xml_payload)
let $test2 :=  fn:encode-for-uri($test)
let $response := xdmp:http-get(fn:concat($smart_uri,'?XML_INPUT=',$test2))
(: Response has the tag information :)
(: parse the response to look like the values I want :)

let $tags := (
  for $tag in $response//response/STRUCTUREDDOCUMENT/META
    let $tag_map := map:map()

    let $_ := 
    (: this one should not be stored :)
  if ($tag/@name = 'Type') then 
        ()
      else
        let $_ := map:put($tag_map, 'name', $tag/@name)
        let $_ := map:put($tag_map, 'value', $tag/@value)
        let $_ := map:put($tag_map, 'id', $tag/@id)
        let $_ := map:put($tag_map, 'score', $tag/@score)
        let $_ := map:put($tag_map, 'key', $tag/@key)
        let $_ := map:put($tag_map, 'original_key', $tag/@original_key)
        let $_ := map:put($tag_map, 'cskey', $tag/@cskey)
        let $_ := map:put($tag_map, 'tag_source', 'smartlogic')

         return $_
    let $ret :=
          (: Only send back maps that are populated :)
      if (map:count($tag_map) > 0) then
         $tag_map
       else ()

    return $ret
)

(: some testing :)
let $doc_as_json := xdmp:to-json($doc)
let $test_map := map:map()
let $_ := map:put($test_map, 'tags', xdmp:to-json($tags))

let $_ := xdmp:log($tags)
let $_ := xdmp:node-replace($doc//headers/tags, array-node { $tags  }  )
let $_ := xdmp:log($doc)
(: return the updated $doc :)
return xdmp:to-json($doc)
```

In the production Scneario, the document will be received VIA a **PUT** request, and will not already be in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things: 1) `xdmp:node-replace` replaces the database nodes, not in-memory nodes. 2) The database updates you make during a transaction are not visible by reading from the database or from the in-memory nodes.

It sounds like you may be updating the tags node correctly with `xdmp:node-replace` but then overwriting everything at the end with `xdmp:document-insert`. I can't be sure without seeing more of your code, but first try removing the final insert from your query.

Comment: Tried with and without the last line. I will update my OP with my full query console (some of it may be extraneous for the purpose of this question)

Comment: Updated OP with Query Console Code.. It is under active development

Comment: @Busturdust you correctly updated the doc in the database, but the transaction from which the update occurs cannot see the committed update, so when you return the JSON transformed `$doc` it's the version from before your updates. If you make a request to read the same URI after running your query *in a separate transaction*, the document will have been updated.

Comment: I run the code, open up a new query console and run `fn:doc()` for it, and still shows `tags=[]`

Comment: @Busturdust can you confirm via `xdmp:log` that during your update 1) `$doc//headers/tags/xdmp:node-uri(.)` is not empty or a sequence, and that `$tags` actually contains the data you expect?

Comment: I've confirmed `$tags` has data, I will confirm the other and get back

Comment: `$doc//headers/tags/xdmp:node-uri(.)` prints a blank line... Not sure what that means however.... I can see `tags=[]` when I do a `fn:doc`

Comment: @Busturdust It means that either `//headers/tags` does not exist in `$doc` or that `$doc` is not a database node. I.e.: if you construct your own nodes in XQuery, they are in-memory nodes and can't be updated through the database (because they don't technically exist in the db yet).

Comment: Is there a way I should be doing this in memory and then manually commiting at the end?

Comment: Yes, it just requires transforming the whole document. The classic way to do this is to write a recursive `typeswitch` function, which is basically the XQuery equivalent of XSLT. There are also libraries you can use that simplify the process like https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations

Comment: Thanks for the help @wst ... A lot to digest at end of a week :) I will do some research and hopefully be able to solve this

Comment: @Busturdust The idea that the updates aren't visible until after the transaction completes takes some getting used to. This blog post is a good primer on XQuery transformations http://blog.davidcassel.net/2014/01/recursive-descent-in-xquery/.

Comment: as a quick test, I did a dumb copy of creating a new map in memory and manually writing everything to the map, and it appears to work, I will work on cleanup and appropriate coding structures next week. Thanks for helping me understand this

Comment: XSLT is also a fast and efficient option for transforming. You can even embed the XSLT in your XQuery and then use `xdmp:xslt-eval()` to see the results immediately. Then, if you are happy with the result, save the document with `xdmp:document-insert()`